# Retrieve all domain names

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code

```
            using (var winNT = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:"))
            {
                foreach (DirectoryEntry child in winNT.Children)
                {
                    if (String.Compare(child.SchemaClassName, "Domain", true) == 0)
                    {
                        _AvailableDomains.Add(child.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

On some machines (I have just test it on Win 2016) it displays a list of domains: WORKGROUP, Local machine name, the company domain. Bu on the others the list is empty. First I thought it stopped working but some work colleagues when they run the code still see the list; I cannot see it (and we have same OS, same .Net framework installed).

Comment: will that be a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to work with following code:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.dll;

using (var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
{
    foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
    {
        _AvailableDomains.Add(domain.Name);
        domain.Dispose();
    }
}
```